# Remove Various Whitespaces While Editing in Vim

Tags: vim, newline, whitespace

So oftentimes, while editing with Vim, I'll get into a variety of situations where whitespace gives me hassle. For example, say I have a comment like this:

```
#This program was featured on the Today show, it is an algorithm for promoting world peace in third-world countries
#given the name of that country and the name of a celebrity to endorse its cause
```

If I want to, for example, trim the lines so they go to X characters, I end up putting a newline somewhere in the middle of the top line to get this (after hitting the newline and auto-indenting):

```
#This program was featured on the Today show, it is an algorithm for promoting
world peace in third-world countries
#given the name of that country and the name of a celebrity to endorse its cause
```

I then add a # to the beginning of the line, and that's all well and good, but then I want that line to line up, too. To do so, I have to delete the newline, all the whitespace for the indent on the next line, and then the commenting # mark. It doesn't take an awfully long amount of time to do that, but this and similar situations all add up over a day's worth of coding.

Now the example above is pretty specific, but my question isn't. What's a good way in Vim to delete all whitespace INCLUDING NEWLINES up until the next non-whitespace character? If Vim already has movements that do that, that would be awesome, but if not, does anyone have a favorite Vim function they use to do the above that could be mapped to a key? At the very least, am I missing some Vim usage idiom that prevents me from even having to worry about this case?

EDIT: Formatting to width, while useful and applicable to the case above, isn't the focus of this question. I'm concerned more with whitespace removal that doesn't stop at the end of a line, but instead carries on to the first non-whitespace character of the next line.

Comment: doesn't `dw` work? Also, for your original problem, don't `gwap` or `gqap` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command seems to work:

```
:.s/\W*$\n\W*//g
```

it uses a replace to remove whitespace up to end of line and the new line at the end.

In this example:

```
testting                 aad        $            
asdjkasdjsdaksddjk$
```

(to see meta characters in vim use the command `:set list`)

if you place the cursor on the first line and use the first command it will delete everything from aad to $ (not including aad but including $ and a newline.)

Also, note for what you are doing it is far more efficient to use an external program to format comments for you. In particular, [par](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Par_text_reformatter) is a great small C program that edits text and wraps it to desired lengths.

If you have `par` in your path, to do what you are trying to do is as easy as selecting the block of comment with `Shift+v` and running the command

```
:!par 40pgr
```

where 40 is the desired width in columns.

If you are feeling hackish, write your own program in C/perl/C++/python that edits comments however you like, then put it in path and use the external filter command `:!` to process blocks of text through it.

Comment: Nice, I didn't expect it to span, but then it did.

Answer (score 1):

You really just want to reformat that comment to fit the current `'textwidth'`.  If the comment is a paragraph (i.e., separated by a line of whitespace above and below), then you can just use `gqip` (`gq` is the reformat command, `ip` is the "inner-paragraph" text object) to reformat it.  If it's not a standalone paragraph, you can visually select those lines and then use `gq`.

This likely also relies on having `'formatoptions'` set correctly to make sure the comment characters are handled properly, but in many cases the ftplugin has already done that.

Comment: This is really good to know for the comment case specifically. What about for code in general that's not very paragraph-centric?

Comment: @wilsona, `d/\ze\S<CR>`.  That's the nice thing about Vim's commands.  They operate over any motion.  `/\ze\S` searches for the position just before the next non-whitespace character, so use that as a motion for the `d` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is a while later, but I found that there is a command that does what I need to in 90% of circumstances:

```
J --  join line below to the current one
```